# Сложить числа массива пока выполняются условия

Tags: php, массивы

У меня есть массив который складывает значения - вывод всегда 2х-3х значное число.

нужно написать условие, которе будет получит однозначное число путем сложения чисел из которых состоит 2-х или 3-х значное число
Но где выполняются дополнительные условия,

**конечное число x  >=1 AND <= 9 OR = 11 OR = 12.**

> Например:  х = 79 - Двухзначное 7+9 = 16 -Двухзначное 16 = 1+6 = 7
>   (оно больше 1 и меньше 9 и не равно 11 или 12)
>
> x = 134 трехзначное 1+3+4 = 7 (оно больше 1 и меньше 9 и не равно 11
>   или 12)

```
  <?

    $string1 = iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1251', $number1);
    foreach (str_split($string1) as $value1) {
        $ov1 = ord($value); 
        $sum_number1+=$ov1;
    }

    $string2 = iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1251', $number2);
    foreach (str_split($string2) as $value2) {
        $ov2 = ord($value); 
        $sum_number2+=$ov2;
    }

    $string3 = iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1251', $number3);
    foreach (str_split($string3) as $value3) {
        $ov3 = ord($value3);    
        $sum_number3+=$ov3;
    }

    $total_number = $sum_number1 + $sum_number2 + $sum_number1;


    $total_number =  'Это и есть число к которому нужно применить условия указанные выше';
?>
```

Comment: А в чем проблема добавить ваши условия?

Comment: у меня затуп какой-то 5-й час туплю не могу сообразить.

Comment: Код существующий добавьте в вопрос.

Comment: добавил код в вопрос

Comment: получаем 3 числа, далее 3 числа складываем и получаем конечное число Х на которое нужно прмиенить условие